# Beginner help: Print Table with sum

Tags: c++

So a simple project for school required that I print a 10x10 table where each entry in the table is the sum of the row and column number. I also need to add an accumulator that will calculate the sum of all the table entries and print it outside the nested loop with a cout statement.

I've got the table portion completed, but can't seem to figure out how to have it output the sums of each column and row. What am I forgetting?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int r, c;
    for (r = 1; r <= 10; r++)
    {
        for (c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
            cout << setw(3) << r;
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause"); // keeps DOS screen open until a key is pressed
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only writing the row `cout << setw(3) << r;` but you are required to write the row plus the column. Seems like `cout << setw(3) << r+c;` might do the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum for each row, consider adding a variable `rowSum`.

The code should be pretty self explanatory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int r, c;
    for (r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
        int rowSum = 0; // reset for each row
        for (c = 1; c <= 10; c++) {
            cout << setw(3) << r + c;
            rowSum += (r + c); // add number to current row sum
        }
        cout << " Row sum = " << rowSum << endl;
    }
    system("pause"); // keeps DOS screen open until a key is pressed
    return 0;
}
```

If you also need column sum, consider keeping a `vector` or `array` of `int` each representing the sum of one column.

Every time you print a number, add it to the corresponding sum.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I think the way I typed the problem may have been a bit vague. Instead of getting rowSum and outputting at the end of each row, I need to get the sum of EACH entry in the table and only output that total one time at the end. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh and we haven't learned array and vector yet so I cannot utilize those in this program. Just a heads up.